# Kein Subjekt? Oder frage ich Falsch?

Tags: grammaticality

Frage:

> Menschen wie dir geht es nur um Krieg.

Täusche ich mich, oder handelt es sich hier um einen reinen Dativsatz, ohne Nominativ? Wenn ja, wie Frage ich denn hier nach dem Nominativ, mit "Wer oder Was" komme ich nicht weit....und wenn "Menschen wie dir" im Dativ steht, hat dieser Satz eben nur Objekt und Prädikat? Scusi, etwas verwirrt...

Desweiteren schleichen sich mir bei Sätzen, die ich ähnlich wie dem obigen, mit "Menschen wie..." anfange, Fehler beim Pronomen ein (also Menschen wie dich/dir/du...) kann mir jemand um einen sicheren Umgang hier helfen? Vlt wie ich richtigerweise den Kasus bestimme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Satz

*Menschen wie dir geht es nur um Krieg.*

enthält ein Subjekt: *es*, ein so genanntes "unpersönliches *es*". Ein solches unpersönliches *es* ist bei einigen wenigen Verben zwingend erforderlich *(Es regnet.)*, bei anderen Verben - so wie hier - wird es nur in manchen Bedeutungen benötigt: *[jemandem]<sub>Dativobjekt</sub> geht es [um etwas]<sub>Präpositionalobjekt</sub>*. Solche Konstruktionspläne muss man jeweils zusammen mit dem Verb lernen.

Das Prädikat des Satzes ist *gehen*. Es tritt hier zusammen mit dem Präpositionalobjekt *um Krieg* auf. *Krieg* steht einfach deswegen ihm Akkusativ, weil die Präposition *um* den Akkusativ verlangt.

*Menschen wie dir* ist im Beispiel das Dativobjekt. *wie dir* ist dabei das Attribut zu *Menschen*. Bei attributiven als/wie-Phrasen richtet sich der Kasus nach dem der Nominalphrase. Mit anderen Worten: *dir* steht im Dativ, weil *Menschen* im Dativ steht. Deswegen heißt es zum Beispiel auch: *Ich mag Menschen wie dich.*

Answer (score 1):

> Menschen wie dir geht es nur um Krieg.
>
> Es geht um Krieg.

Das Subjekt ist **es**.

---

Der Fall des Personalpronomens ergibt sich aus der Rolle im Satz. Im Satz

> Es geht dir nur um Krieg.

lautet das Prädikat *gehen um*. Das Akkusativobjekt dieses Verbs ist das Thema, das Dativobjekt derjenige, der das Thema festlegt.

> Es geht Menschen wie dir nur um Krieg.

Hier ist *Menschen wie dir* das Dativobjekt.

> Es geht einem Menschen wie dir nur um Krieg.

Hier *einem Menschen wie dir*.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Puh, scheint wohl doch so komplex zu sein, wie ich angenommen hatte. Damit meine ich, dass man mit den Hilfsfragen: Wer oder Was usw. hier nicht weit kommt, right?

Comment: _um Krieg_ ist allerdings ein Präpositionalobjekt; der Akkusativ ergibt sich nicht aus dem Verb, sondern wird von _um_ gefordert.

Comment: Ich halte *gehen um* für ein zusammengesetztes Verb. Die Grenzen sind fließend.

Comment: 'Gehen um' ist etwas anderes als das trennbare 'umgehen' (ein Gespenst geht um in Europa) und das nicht trennbare 'umgehen' (das Problem lässt sich nicht lösen, aber man kann es umgehen). Die Frage ist aber schon: Was ist hier das Prädikat? Damit zusammenhängend: Wie ist die Information topikalisiert? Meine (vorläufige) Auffassung  dazu wäre: 'um Krieg gehen' = Prädikat; 'Menschen' = 'Satzgegenstand' im klassischen Verständnis, das, worüber etwas ausgesagt wird; 'es' = Platzhaltersubjekt, hier anders als bei 'ihm wurde schwindlig' nicht weglassbar.

Comment: _es_ hier als Platzhalter zu bezeichnen, halte ich für unpassend, da kein "Platz" (= sonst leerer Satzabschnitt) ausgefüllt wird (anders: _Es hat richtig Spaß gemacht_ mit _es_ als Vorfeldplatzhalter). Würde daher bei der klassischen Bezeichnung als unpersönl. (Subjekt-)es bleiben. Ob man bei _es_ von einem Subjekt sprechen kann (formal ist es das gewiss), lässt sich diskutieren; ich bin da liberaler, manche würden es wohl bestreiten, weil ein echtes Paradigma fehlt (in dem Fall wäre der Satz als subjektlos zu werden). Präp.komplement _um Krieg_ sollte man wohl zum Prädikatsausdruck zählen.

Answer (score 0):

Zur zweiten Frage - woher weiß ich, welchen Kasus eine Ergänzung haben muss? - kann ich nur folgende Antwort geben: Sie müssen schlicht und einfach mit den Verben mitgelernt werden, vergleichbar den Genera bei den Nomen. Mit der Zeit
bilden sich dann hoffentlich im Sprachbewusstsein Cluster von bedeutungsanalogen Strukturen. Bezogen auf die Ausgangsfrage kämen in Frage

> gehen um (es) = Thema sein: *es geht hier und heute um die Betriebsratswahl*
>
> gehen um (es) = zur Entscheidung stehen: *es geht um alles, um die Wurst*
>
> jm gehen um (es) = für jn wichtig sein: *mir geht es hier nicht um das Geld*
>
> bei jm gehen um (es) = beabsichtigen: *bei ihm geht es immer nur um das eine*
>
> für jn gehen um (es) = entschieden werden: *für ihn geht es um alles oder nichts*
>
> jm +Adj gehen (es) = Aussage über das Wohlbefinden: *es geht ihm wieder besser*

Es gibt 'jemandem geht es um' als durchgängig stabile Basisstruktur, in die verschiedene Ergänzungen eingehängt werden können. Eine analoge Struktur hat

> jm ist es zu tun um = wichtig für jn sein: *ihm ist es um die Sicherheit zu tun*

Ähnlich auch:

> jm ein Anliegen / ein Herzensbedürfnis ... sein (zu / dass)

Will man ähnliche Inhalte mit anderen Verben ausdrücken, muss man diese Verben in den Strukturen benutzen, welche für sie vorgesehen sind:

> für jn keine / kaum / nur eine geringe / große Bedeutung / Wichtigkeit haben
>
> Wert legen auf
>
> (bei jm) sich drehen um: *bei ihm dreht sich alles nur ums Geld*
>
> es zu tun haben mit: *wir haben es hier mit einem besonders schwierigen Fall zu tun*
>
> handeln von: *Der Film handelt von den Folgen der Dürre in Kalifornien.*
>
> etw. behandeln: *Der Film behandelt ...*

usw.

Wichtig wäre dabei, sich klar zu machen, dass das 'es' Nominativ und Subjekt ist und dass es außer in Sätzen mit Prädikativen - das sind im wesentlichen Sätze mit 'sein', 'bleiben' und 'werden' - keine zwei Nominative geben kann. Auch zwei (nicht präpositionengesteuerte) Akkusative sind sehr selten (*das kostete mich nur ein Lächeln, das geht dich einen feuchten Schmutz an*), so dass wir in diesen gehen-um-Sätzen eine ziemlich gängige Struktur haben: Subj (es) + V (gehen) + jm + präpos. Objekt, wobei hier der Dativ 'jm' keinen 'Empfänger' bezeichnet, sondern eine etwas (in Gradabstufungen von Relevanz) wollende Person.

Was die Appositionen (Anhängsel) hinter 'wie' und 'als' betrifft, gilt die grundsätzliche Regel, dass sie mit dem Bezugswort kongruieren: *Dir als einem sehr kompetenten Deutschsprecher brauche ich das wohl nicht zu erklären.* Da im Ausgangssatz das Nomen 'Menschen' Dativ sein muss - das weiß man aber nur, wenn man die Struktur kennt, von der Form her könnte es jeder beliebige Kasus sein -, muss auch das 'du' in den Dativ gesetzt werden, und so heißt es dann 'Menschen wie dir'.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die ausführliche Antwort. Kannst du hier auch noch kurz drüber schaun? Das hatte ich oben bereits in einem Kommentar eingefügt: 

"Menschen wie du haben es schwer..", Prädikat-> haben; Menschen wie du-> Nominativ? (oder ist das Subjekt nur "du"?) es schwer-> Akkusativ? Und das hier: "Menschen wie dich gibt es auch"; "es" wieder unpersönliches Nominativ? "Menschen wie dich" -> Akkussativ? "gibt" das Prädikat....aber was ist mit dem "auch"?

Vielen Dank für die Mühe :)

Comment: Alles richtig, was Du schreibst. Der Begriff 'Prädikat' ist nicht einheitlich definiert. Manche verstehen darunter u.a. mehrteilige Verbverbände (hatte nichts davon wissen wollen), andere zusätzlich mehr oder weniger stark integrierte Ergänzungen (einen trinken gehen = 1 Prädikat). Das 'auch' im Satz 'Menschen wie Dich gibt es auch' verstehe ich nicht, allenfalls in Sätzen wie 'zum Glück gibt es (hier) auch (noch) Menschen wie dich.' Die angehängten 'wie'-Appositionen sind weglassbar, also Attribute wie Adjektive (große Menschen haben es schwer), Subjekte/Objekte sind die Bezugsworte davor.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Ja das "auch", wenn man z.B. sagen würde, dass jemand deines "Schlags" auch in dieser Veranstaltung zu finden wäre. Das alles sind auch Satzfragmente, die ich bilde (auch wenn das nicht sehr intellektuell ist), wenn ich gewisse Stereotype bzw. Verhaltensweisen verallgemeinere. Vielen Dank nochmal :)

Comment: Satzfragmente sind kein schlechtes Experimentierfeld. Man muss sich dabei rückversichern, so wie Du hier, denn manche Satzelemente sind z.B. nicht weglassbar, oder man würde sich überhaupt ganz anders ausdrücken. Für das unerwartete Treffen auf einer Veranstaltung haben wir 'Du hier (und nicht in Hollywood)!?' oder 'Was machst **du** denn hier?'. Geht es um die 'Sorte Mensch', könnte man sagen 'dass ich jemanden wie dich hier treffe ...! (hätte ich nicht erwartet)', oder 'sieh mal an, hier gibt es sogar so welche wie dich' (klingt seltsam) oder ... [weiter ...]

Comment: [... weiter] ... 'wie jetzt!, hier gibt's auch (so) Leute wie dich?' (klingt auch etwas ungewöhnlich, wäre aber korrekt). Etwas 'normaler' wäre 'was macht / was will jemand wie du auf 'nem Metal-Konzert, ich dachte du sitzt zu Hause mit 'nem Kräutertee und liest Rilke-Gedichte!' Wie auch immer du es drehst, der Ort bzw. ein **hier** ist nicht weglassbar.